# Jordan-Hölder and prime factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Let $\mathfrak{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers.

Given an integer $a>0$, let $(\nu_{p}(a))_{p\in\mathfrak{p}}$ be a family of positive integers with finite support such that

$$a=\prod_{p\in\mathfrak{P}} p^{\nu_{p}(a)}.$$

How can one deduce the uniqueness of the family $(\nu_{p}(a))_{p\in\mathfrak{p}}$?

Suppose ($\mu_{p}(a))_{p\in\mathfrak{p}}$ is another family satisfying the above requirements. Let $(f_{k})_{1\leq k\leq n}$ and $(g_{j})_{1\leq j\leq m}$ be sequences of elements of the support of $(\nu_{p}(a))_{p\in\mathfrak{p}}$ and ($\mu_{p}(a))_{p\in\mathfrak{p}}$, respectively.  Then

$$\big(\Pi^{k}f_{k}^{\nu_{f_k}(a)}\mathbb{Z}\ / \ a\mathbb{Z}\big)_{0\leq k\leq n}$$

$$\big(\Pi^{j}g_{j}^{\mu_{g_j}(a)}\mathbb{Z}\ / \ a\mathbb{Z}\big)_{0\leq j\leq m}$$

are two Jordan-Hölder series belonging to $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$. By Jordan-Hölder, $m=n$ and

$$f_{k+1}^{\nu_{f_{k+1}}(a)}=g_{\sigma (k)+1}^{\mu_{g_{\sigma (k)+1}}(a)}$$

for $0\leq k \leq n-1$, where $\sigma$ is a permutation of the interval $[0,n-1]$.

Question: how can I go on to conclude that the two families are equal from this position?

I would like this proof to be complete w.r.t the technical (formal?) details. Therefore, while I appreciate all your help, please refrain from giving "prose-laden" answers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't this just the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Comment: It is—but I would like to prove it using this setup, if that's all right.